# how to get total filesize of the files when only the links are availble

Tags: bash, filesize

In Linux I have a directory with links to some files anywhere in the system. Now I would like to get the total filesize of these files where these links are referenced to.  Can anyone here tell me how this is to be done?
THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `du -shL <dirname>`.
From the du manpage:

```
-L, --dereference
        dereference all symbolic links
```

Comment: Nice, I was about to post a `stat` based answer but this is much better. Definitely the right tool for the job.